# I want to change the ibeacon flags value

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, flags, ads

I am currently developing an android app, and when I scan it with nrf connect, it appears as 0x02011A in the flags section.

I want to change to 0x020106.

I would be grateful if you could give me an example and tell me which source to use.

Comment: https://github.com/youten/aBeacon

Comment: It is currently in production using open source. Which part should I change?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the flags value to 0x06 from 0x1A effectively changes the advertisement so bits 1 and 2 are set, indicating that "BR/EDR Not Supported" by the device.

```
bit 0 (OFF) LE Limited Discoverable Mode
bit 1 (ON) LE General Discoverable Mode
bit 2 (OFF) BR/EDR Not Supported
bit 3 (ON) Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (controller)
bit 4 (ON) Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Host)
```

These bits are normally set by the operating system, and since Android hardware devices support "Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable" for both Host and Controller, those bits are normally set instead.

**Unfortunately, the Android operating system provides no API to configure these flags.**  The [AdvertiseSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.Builder) class allows you to configure whether the advertisement is connectible, which adds a new PDU with its own flags, but does not let you alter these flags.

Unless you can build your own Android ROM on a rooted device, I am afraid this is not possible.